# cruisecontrol <buildargs> nant parameter not being passed

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant, cruisecontrol

I've been trying to use the  param in my cruisecontrol build config file to no avail.  When checking the cruisecontrol log file, whatever buildargs I try to pass are NOT passed to the call to nAnt.

Here's the nant task:

```
<nant>
  <buildArgs>-D:CCFoo="Unknown" -D:foo="$(foo)"</buildArgs>
  <executable>C:\MCR\Trunk\BuildLibrary\NAnt.exe</executable>
  <baseDirectory>C:\MCR\Trunk\tek.Build</baseDirectory>
  <buildFile>tek.build</buildFile>
  <targetList>
    <target>cc</target>
  </targetList>
  <buildTimeoutSeconds>1800</buildTimeoutSeconds>
</nant>
```

Here's what appears in the logfile for that call to nant:

```
2010-01-28 08:45:12,815 [TekWebsite:DEBUG] Starting process [C:\MCR\Trunk\BuildLibrary\NAnt.exe] in working directory [C:\MCR\Trunk\tek.Build] with arguments [-nologo -buildfile:tek.build -logger:NAnt.Core.XmlLogger -D:CCNetArtifactDirectory="C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\builds" -D:CCNetBuildCondition=ForceBuild -D:CCNetBuildDate=2010-01-28 -D:CCNetBuildTime=08:45:12 -D:CCNetFailureUsers= -D:CCNetIntegrationStatus=Unknown -D:CCNetLabel=50 -D:CCNetLastIntegrationStatus=Failure -D:CCNetListenerFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\builds\ClarksWebsite_ListenFile.xml" -D:CCNetModifyingUsers= -D:CCNetNumericLabel=50 -D:CCNetProject=TekWebsite -D:CCNetProjectUrl=http://cor-str-mcr08/ccnet/server/local/project/TekWebsite/ViewProjectReport.aspx -D:CCNetRequestSource=Dashboard -D:CCNetWorkingDirectory="C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server" cc]
```

I'm thinking that maybe there's a config setting for cruisecontrol that tells it to ignore buildargs?

I've tried reordering the lines in the nant task, putting buildargs at the top as you see, and a few places in the middle and the bottom.  I've tried the different syntaxes that are available for buildargs such as:

-D:CCFoo="Unknown"
-D:CCFoo=Unknown
-DCCFoo=Unknown

Comment: I figured this out - the ccnet.config file that's used by the ccnet daemon process won't reload the build config file until either:

a) the process is restarted OR
b) the ccnet.config file is altered or touched in some way.

So I just went into C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server.ccnet.config and added a space, saved and now the buildargs are being passed to nant.  woohoo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out - the ccnet.config file that's used by the ccnet daemon process won't reload the build config file until either:

a) the process is restarted OR
b) the ccnet.config file is altered or touched in some way.

So I just went into C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server.ccnet.config and added a space, saved and now the buildargs are being passed to nant. woohoo!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem running some bat file but my reason was I has used:

```
<msbuild>
  ...
```

instead of

```
<exec>
  ...
```